# Object placeholder in CKEditor

Tags: flash, object, ckeditor, flv, placeholder

I'm trying to write a little ckEditor plugin to implement the [flv-player](http://flv-player.net/). After the code is implemented in the content area the CKEDitor just place a placeholder if there is a embed tag in the object tag, but I don't want to use embed tag. I made a dirty hack (wich does not update the params width and height on resize) in ckEdiotr.js but I was wondering if there is maybe a clean solution or if someone had same issues or if there is already a plugin for a flv player.

I changed the Code in ckeditor.js (v. 3.4) if your searching for 'cke:object' and there I changed "return null" after the for-loop so that it will also create a fakeImage for objects with no embed as child.

```
'cke:object':function(t){
  var u=t.attributes,v=u.classid&&String(u.classid).toLowerCase();
  if(!v){
    for(var w=0;w<t.children.length;w++){
      if(t.children[w].name=='cke:embed'){
        if(!o(t.children[w]))return null;
        return p(q,t);
      }
    }
    return p(q,t); //old: return null
  }
  return p(q,t);
},
```

Comment: why not just take another one flash player plugin and change it? What a dirty hack you made? Please share some snippets from your code. Thanks!

Comment: i would use another flash player plugin, but i couldnt find one !?

Comment: @Eugene: do you know of an example? Would also be interested to see.